# class that represents an item with attributes where attributes are in a collection of attribute objects, using code first migrations

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do a code first entity framework project that consists of two classes/tables.
One class represents an widget. The second class/table contains attributes of this widget. i.e. right threaded, left threaded, small, large, etc..

Each Widget could have 1 or more attributes and each attribute could belong to many widgets.

I'm drawing a blank on how this should be represented in code first.

```
    class Widget{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public ICollection<Attribute> Attributes{get; set;}
    }

    class Attribute{
      public int Id{ get; set;}
      public string Name{get; set;}
    }
```

The classes above give me two tables and multiple copies of the same attribute in the DB.

Ultimately I am trying to use the Attribute table as an expandable enum of sorts.

Comment: I think I need to add an intermediary table. i.e. WidgetAttributes

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have a navigation property on the Attribute entity, Entity Framework won't determine by convention that a many-to-many relationship is present. It will create a one-to-many instead. To specify a many-to-many relationship, you need to add mapping code to the context.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>()
        .HasMany(w => w.Attributes)
        .WithMany();
}
```

The .Map() code in the example you linked is only necessary if you wish to specify column or table names. If you omit that code, Entity Framework will provide names.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a related article that explained it well. I am concerned about the age of the article and whether anything has changed since 2011.
[Many to Many article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First)